# What's another name for object_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just realized one of my models has `object_id` as a column, and that's going to cause prolems.

Any suggestions on possible alternatives for the name `object_id`?

Comment: Please tell me you don't have `class Object < ActiveRecord::Base`!

Answer (score 3):

What is this column supposed to be mapping to?  Is it a foreign key to an ***objects*** table?

Figure out what you're really trying to represent.  It's probably not just any generic thing in the whole world.  (If it is, maybe ***things*** is a better name.)

If you're working under constraints and you absolutely must have that `object_id` column, you could still refer to it directly with `attributes[:object_id]` and bypass Rails's magic methods.

As a last resort, you could overwrite the method with your own `#object_id` method that simply returns that attribute from your database (this is what Rails did with the `#id` method).  I can't think of anything that would *definitely* break off the top of my head, but it's probably not a great idea.  The object ID is used for a lot of miscellaneous things, so you may get strange behavior if you do object comparisons, use your object as a hash key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `object_id` at in your model. And there should be no column named `object_id` in the database.

`object_id` is just a default methods that all (except `BasicObject` in Ruby 1.9) objects have (see [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001004)).

> Returns an integer identifier for obj.
>   The same number will be returned on
>   all calls to id for a given object,
>   and no two active objects will share
>   an id.
>   **Replaces the deprecated Object#id**.

```
2.object_id # 5 or anything, but the same
2.id # NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for 2:Fixnum
2.object_id # 5
"anything has object_id".object_id # 22522080
"anything has object_id".object_id # 22447200 - string has different object_id because it's a new instance everytime
```

So, just use `id` to access database identifier of ActiveRecord classes. That is the one created by Ruby On Rails for model objects.

---

**OR** if you do need to have the column in the database called object_id then you can create a method on the ActiveRecord model like this:

```
def general_id
  read_attribute(:object_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised that Rails doesn't create `__object_id__` as a reference to the original form of `object_id`, like `send` has a Ruby variant called `__send__`.

**Edit:** The Ruby method `__id__` appears to be the `__send__` equivalent for `object_id`. It may be safe to use `object_id` as a method for your foreign key, or it may not. I don't actually use Rails in my current job.

Comment: That `__send__` alias isn't a Rails thing, it's a core Ruby method. The RDocs for it even state: _"You can use `__send__` if the name `send` clashes with an existing method in **obj.**"_  That's a much more common case than the original poster's clash on `object_id` -- and he could just as easily make such an alias if he wanted.