# Is it theoretically safe to redefine any Ruby method that doesn't begin with underscores?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

For example, is it theoretically safe to modify `Object#object_id` since there's always `Object#__id__` if you really need to know what an object's id is?

**Background:** Curiosity piqued by [What's another name for object_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255310/whats-another-name-for-object-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ideal system where everything is perfectly documented and all people working with the code are aware of what's been re-defined and patched - then yes, maybe.

But as we all know, such situations rarely exist. Personally, I feel that patching anything already defined in `Kernel`, `Class`, `Module` or `Object` is a no-no (unless you're doing it at a framework level.)

Ultimately, I believe that Principle of Least Surprise should permeate coding decisions at *all* levels.

Comment: Also, in some implementation (Rubinius in particular), changing the behavior of a core method can affect other core methods.

Answer (score 2):

> is it theoretically safe to modify Object#object_id

Well, I think we are probably more concerned with reality than theory here.  The fact is, people aren't going to use the `__X__` version until they realize that you have overriden and completely jacked up the default behavior.  With power comes responsibility; use monkey-patching carefully and never introduce unexpected behavior.  Better just to add a new method to the class instead.